# Centering Text & Text Box

Tags: html, css

CSS:

```
    body{
        width: 100%;
        color: black;
        margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    }
    header .top-bar{
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
        height: 35px;
        border-top: 4px solid #1ce5d9;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
        vertical-align: middle;
        color: gray;
    }

    header .top-bar .top-bar-left{
        float: left;
    }

    header .top-bar .top-bar-right{
        float: right;
        vertical-align:top;
    }

    header .top-bar li{
        display: inline;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    header .top-bar .active{
        text-decoration: none; 
        color: #1ce5d9;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 140%;
    }

    header .top-bar .active:hover{
        text-decoration: none; 
        color: #1ce5d9;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
```

HTML:

```
            <header>
                <div class="top-line"></div>
                <div class="top-bar">
                    <div class="top-bar-left">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#" class="active">TRENDING</a></li>
                            <li>Some Random Text</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    <div class="top-bar-right">
                        <input type="text" class="search-box">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <nav>
                    <div class="logo">
                        <img src="img/logo.png">
                    </div>

                    <div class="nav-bar">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="active"><a href="">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Features</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Shop</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Forums</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </header>
```

The issue I'm having I want the text and text box to be in the middle of the div horizontally. I've tired looking on google but I can't find anything that works...

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

At first, `text` `li` tag is inside another div. So you can't center it along with your text box.

So group them together in the same div like this:

```
<div class="top-bar-right">
               <li>Some Random Text</li>
               <input type="text" class="search-box">
</div>
```

After that if you remove `float: right` present in the `top-bar-right` it will align center.

Comment: Okay and how do I center it on the top and bottom? As at the moment its right on the bottom of it and I want it in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove class 'top-bar-left' and add a width for your divs and margin-left and margin-right to auto.

like this: style="width:300px; margin:10px auto;"